# I want to reset the level in Unity and don't reset the variable too

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to reset level in Unity and don't reset the coin amount variable and the lose counter variable. I use `playerprefs` but it doesn't work to me the variable reset too.

```
public void EndGame()
{
    LoseCounter++;
    Invoke("Restart", restartDelay);      
}
public void Restart()
{
    savedata();
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    loaddata();
}
public void savedata()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("coinamount", ct.coinAmount);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("losecounter", LoseCounter);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
public void loaddata()
{
    ct.coinAmount = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("coinamount");
    LoseCounter = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("losecounter");
}
```

script cointext

```
public int coinAmount;   
public Text text;
void Start()
{
    text = GetComponent<Text>();
}
void Update()
{
    text.text = coinAmount.ToString() + " coins";
}
```

Comment: in restart i delete  the Parenthesis in worng

Comment: Don't use PlayerPrefs to store game state.

Comment: Try using static variables

Answer (score 1):

make sure you are calling loaddata() in the Start() method.

once you call the "Load scene" method, the lines of code under it will not be called.

so make sure you are calling loaddata() in the Start method or OnEnable.

hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I second what [Muhammad Ellawie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7184712/muhammad-ellawie) said about loading data in the `Start()` method.
but as a general rule, those game data should generally not be a part of the scene, you may want to implement a [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for example so they wouldn't be part of the scene.

Comment: @THEFrogEitan if an answer here solved your problem, I suggest you pick one as an answer to your question.
Welcome to stackoverflow :D

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to tell unity to not destroy your game-manager: Call DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject) in the Awake of the monobehaviour to keep it alive after scene reload.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html